# Get the same value twice with jQuery + Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm having trouble with jQuery and KnockoutJS. I'm trying to read a form with radio buttons where you can choose if you're male/female.

profile().gender value is 'm' so the 'checked' thing works. But in the jQuery I should get both alert for 'm' and 'f' but I get 'm' twice.

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="profile gender" name="gender" data-bind="value: 'm', attr: { checked: profile().gender=='m' }" /> Male
<input type="radio" class="profile gender" name="gender" data-bind="value: 'f', attr: { checked: profile().gender=='f' }" /> Female
```

Then read it with this jQuery code:

```
$('.profile').each(function() {
    var self = this;
    alert($('.gender').val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you have to in alert `$('.gender').val()` will always give you first element, you need to give index of element to go through them.

```
$('.profile').each(function(i) {
    var self = this;
    alert($('.gender').eq(i).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Adil has it correct, but this can be simplified since you already have a reference to each element in `this` when you call each:

```
$('.profile.gender').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```